# Use Recursive CTE in SQL Server to get data for all ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to use Recursive CTE in sql to get data for each unique id in a table. I am reading [this tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/), but cannot get my code to work.

My logic is

```
for each unique id in a table = currentId
select * from table
where 
date between
max available date of that currentId
and 
5 days before that max available date of that currentId
```

I tried to do this

```
WITH cte_org AS (
    SELECT * FROM shoes 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte_org 
    WHERE  
    CAST(startTime AS date) 
    BETWEEN  DATEADD(DAY,-30, (select max(CAST(startTime as date)) from shoes where shoeId = cte_org.shoeId )  )
    AND (select max(CAST(startTime as date)) from shoes where shoeId = cte_org.shoeId )
)

 SELECT * FROM cte_org
```

I get

> SQL Error 467 GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'cte_org'

Any help?

EDIT

expected results

```
for shoe id 1
time 14/1/2020 - color black
time 13/1/2020 - color yellow
time 12/1/2020 - color pink
time 11/1/2020 - color orange
time 10/1/2020 - color green

for shoe id 2
time 14/1/2020 - color white
time 13/1/2020 - color green
time 12/1/2020 - color black
time 11/1/2020 - color blue
time 10/1/2020 - color brown

for shoe id 3....etc
```

EDIT 2

```
id   time          color
1    14/1/2020     pink
2    14/1/2020     black
3    14/1/2020     orange
```

Comment: Why do you need an rCTE to get the data for each ID at all? Surely if you don't filter, you get all the IDs. Sample data and expected results well help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu Please check edited question, to see expected form of results. Thanks

Comment: Just need the sample data now.

Comment: @Larnu How can I upload a sample data? Never done it

Comment: Exactly like you did with the expected results is fine. If you want to do one better, do so as DDL and DML.

Comment: @Larnu check edit 2. Does this helps you? Thanks

Comment: Where does yellow come from, when it's not in your sample data? About about green and white?

Comment: @Larnu yes, sorry it is green.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I dont get the question. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH cte_org AS (
        SELECT * FROM shoes 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM cte_org 
        WHERE  
        CAST(startTime AS date) 
        BETWEEN  DATEADD(DAY,-30, (select max(CAST(startTime as date)) from shoes where shoeId = cte_org.shoeId )  )
        AND (Select top 1 CAST(startTime as date) 
 from shoes where shoeId = cte_org.shoeId 
Order by startTime desc)
    )

 SELECT * FROM cte_org
```

OR

```
    WITH cte_org AS (
        SELECT * FROM shoes 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM cte_org 
        WHERE  
        CAST(startTime AS date) 
        BETWEEN  DATEADD(DAY,-30, (select max(CAST(startTime as date)) from shoes where shoeId = cte_org.shoeId )  )
        AND (Select Max(CAST(startTime as date)) OVER ( Partition by shoeId) AS max_date
 from shoes where shoeId = cte_org.shoeId )
    )

 SELECT * FROM cte_org
```

Please try above queries ,if there is any syntax error try to correct it but this is correct logic..

Comment: In principal you are right, nice thinking. But in practice I still get the `SQL Error 467 GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'cte_org'` error. I need to get rid of the `BETWEEN` somehow? Is this an aggregate function? Thanks\